# Meaning of "A new terror born in death......I am legend."

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning

the sentence is below:

> A new terror born in death, a new superstition entering the unassailable fortress of forever, I am legend.
>
> -- Richard Matheson, *I Am Legend*

I can't understand the meaning of sentence.
help me, please.

Comment: When you quote a sentence, please give the source, in order to properly credit the author and help answerers find context if needed.  I have added it this time.

Answer (score 1):

It's from Richard Matheson's, **I Am Legend**.

It's better taken in context. The book ends with the character, who now sees the world populated by monsters taking note of the ironic situation reversal. Now HE has become the monster. "In the eyes of the undead, the vampire slayer is an aberration."

**A new terror born in death** relates to that. Now the undead that populate the planet will have **superstitions** about living vampire slayers.

In this ironic sort of way, he has become a legend.

It's not quite grammatically correct, particularly the "I am legend". It should of course be "I am a legend", but the author does this here for dramatic effect.

Comment: +1 Might add that it isn't quite grammatical, but in a good way.  (Or address the grammaticality, if you disagree.)

Comment: done. I'm wondering if perhaps there should be a spoiler alert also...

Answer (score 1):

Without getting into literary interpretation:

Noun-phrase #1: A new terror born in death
Noun-phrase #2: a new superstition entering the unassailable fortress of forever

Each of these noun phrases is in apposition to "I" in  "I am legend".

I = new terror born in death
I = a new superstition....etc
I am legend.

> A new breakfast cereal, a wholesome treat, Sugar Lumps is delicious.